# my menu is not aligning in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, menu, responsive-design

I got this code from a client and they had issues with IE i solved most of it except the menu
It works fine in all browsers except IE when the browser window is made small as the site is responsive

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vx8H7/

```
index_list li{ font-size: 16px;
               line-height: 16px;
               float:left;}
```

Comment: When asking IE-related questions, please always specify the IE version(s) you're testing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because of the flexbox properties you are using. These aren't supported in IE prior to version 10, in version 10 they are mainly supported with `-ms-` prefixes which I didn't see in your Fiddle.

[Flexbox @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Flexbox guide @ css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks a lot dude will read up on that. This article was a great help